# Inheritance for Python unit tests leads to error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

When I run the snippet below, I get an error:

```
'TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'.
```

However, if I remove the `unittest.Main()` and just create an instance of B: `b = B()`, it works just fine and calls A's constructor as it should.

**EDIT 2**: A is not meant to be run as a unit test. Only A, which inherits B.

**EDIT**: What I want to accomplish with this inheritance (although it's not well-shown in the snippet) is creating a common base class for two unit tests.

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase

class A(TestCase):

    def __init__(self, message):
        print(message)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('It works!')

    def test_function(self):
        print('B - test method')

unittest.main()
```

Comment: What's the point of having constructor arguments? When you run `unittest.main()` and your test cases are instantiated by the unittest module, it won't pass any values for those parameters. They're worse than pointless, they just make problems.

Comment: Class A is not meant to be run as a unit test, just B. I want B to instantiate one of A's fields (not happening in this example) via that constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the `TestCase` constructor has an optional parameter:

> class unittest.TestCase(methodName='runTest')

But your constructor doesn't:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('It works!')
```

That's why when unittest tries to instantiate your test case, the `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` exception you've observed is thrown.

---

When you subclass `TestCase`, you have to account for its parameters. This is best done with varargs `*args, **kwargs`, because that can forward any number of positional or keyword arguments:

```
class A(TestCase):
    def __init__(self, message, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(message)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__('It works!', *args, **kwargs)

    def test_function(self):
        print('B - test method')
```

Make sure not to forget to call `super().__init__` in `A`'s constructor - this was another one of the problems in your code.